# how to disable the row of the grid view

Tags: asp.net

ghyath i am doing in rowdatabound control only but the thing is that whenever i disabled 3rd row of the 1st page it automatically disable the 3rd row of 2nd, 3rd, 4th..... page which i dnt want

Answer (score 1):

You can use   the `PageIndex` and `RowIndex` properties:

```
protected void MyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (GridView) sender;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Enabled = (grid.PageIndex != 0 || e.Row.RowIndex != 2);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to disable the row of a button that was clicked use this approach:

```
protected void BtnDisableRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button) sender).NamingContainer;
    row.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I just went through your this answer. _What If I want to disable the particular row when the button click event is fired._ (Note : each row has its button)

Comment: @nad: handle the button-`Click`-event for all rows with the same handler. Then get the `GridViewRow`. Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

use RowDataBound event >>

protected void gvLeaveDetail_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string status = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "3rdROW"));

```
            if(status== "accept")
            {
              // Cells[7] : 3rd Row then it should be '4' then it will work on only that row 
                e.Row.Cells[7].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else if (status == "reject")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[7].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```